# We want to support internationalization in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization

We are using cakephp 1.2.

Use the locale, we want to make the internationalization.

In cake/console/cake i18n command, we created a default.pot.

The ctp of view, it is described as follows.

```
<title><?php echo __('site_title', true); ?></title>
```

app\locale\eng\LC_MESSAGES\default.po

```
msgid "site_title"
msgstr "welcome my site!"
```

controller

```
App::import('Core', 'l10n');
Configure::write('Config.language', 'en');
```

However, when you view the screen,
it is displayed as "site_title".

the characters specified in the msgid is will be displayed.

Why I do not know is whether the cause this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put this code in your controller ? :

```
$this->L10n = new L10n();
$this->L10n->get("eng");
```

Let's try and tell us.